# How to use Neo4j sum the weights between nodes

Tags: neo4j

I just create a graph like below:

> (User)-[:view]->(Product)<-[:View]-(User)

follow is my query:

```
match (a:User{user_cd:'3151004'})-[r1:view_times]-()-[r2:view_times]-(b:User),
(a)-[ra:view_times]-(),(b)-[rb:view_times]-()
with sum(r1.count) as r1, sum(r2.count) as r2,sum(ra.count) as rac,sum(rb.count) as rbc,a,b
where r1/rac > 0.6 and r2/rbc >0.6
return a,b,rac,rbc,r1,r2
```

r1: the weights between (a) and (product) which is on the connection a and b

r2: the weights between (b) and (product) which is on the connection a and b

rac: all the weights of view_times property connected to (a)

rbc: all the weights of view_times property connected to (b)

But i get the wrong rac,rbc vaule,and i dont know where is wrong

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20169813/neo4j-2-0-summing-up-different-property-weights-problems-with-where-clause

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Neo4j 2.0 - summing up different property weights - Problems with WHERE clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20169813/neo4j-2-0-summing-up-different-property-weights-problems-with-where-clause)

Answer (score 0):

This query needs to be done with more stages. For example:

```
MATCH (ap1:Airport)<-[:FROM]-(r:Route)-[:TO]->(ap2:Airport)
WHERE id(ap1) <> id(ap2)
WITH ap1, ap2, COUNT(*) AS weight
CREATE (ap1)-[c:CONNECTED]->(ap2)
SET c.weight = weight
```

Here I count the number of patterns found in the WITH clause. After the WITH clause, I could add a second MATCH clause.

Comment: thanks, i got it. depends on the usage of WITH clause